# macports is not uninstalling a package

Tags: macports, macos

Earlier today, I tried using `MacPorts` to install `gnutar`.  By doing the following

```
sudo port install gnutar
```

But now I've decided I didn't want to do this.  So I tried to uninstall by doing

```
sudo port uninstall gnutar
```

but the binaries are still in place and functioning.

Why wasn't it uninstalled?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have another port installed that depends on `gnutar`, so the uninstall command didn't remove it. Run

```
port dependents gnutar
```

to see if this is the case (`sudo` is not required for some `port` actions like `list`, `installed`, `dependents`, etc.). If you want to uninstall everyone,

```
sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents gnutar
```

will do the trick, but obviously could lead to unintended consequences, as all the dependents of all the dependents will be uninstalled, recursively, and you could end up decimating your port collection. Only do this if you know exactly what you're doing. `gnutar` is fairly small and unobtrusive, so if you can't easily get rid of it you won't be that bad off in terms of disk space.